# Spring API + Vue JS Web Application slows down extremely in production

Tags: spring, performance, spring-boot, api, heroku

I built a basic web application to learn about Spring Boot and Vue.js.

When running the applications on localhost, everything runs smoothly, i.e. every request needs well under 1 sec.

Now I deployed the application on heroku to put it into production, but the performance slowed down tremendously. Every action that requires an API call takes quite exactly 5-7 seconds.

Of course a slow down is to be expected when using a free hosting provider. However, this is extreme.

Now the region set in Heroku for the Spring API is Europe, the database for the application is in SG and I sit in the PHilippines, which I assume could explain some of the lag.

When following the logs in heroku, the API call shows up about 6 seconds after I send it, with the response coming right after (<1sec).

Which leads to my question:

How will I be able to find the bottleneck here and what can I do to fix this?

Here is the link for the API (the api contains only demo data, so please don't mind the exposed passwords...) 
https://brownbag-api.herokuapp.com/api/pos/all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the delay between the Spring Boot API and the MySQL database.

Moving to a database on the same dyno as the Spring boot API fixed the issue.